# Pass args to a java executable Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: java, arguments, parameter-passing, macos-big-sur, mainclass

Hello I'm learning java and want to pass arguments to main class in a java executable (.jar) in Mac OS Big Sur. Its only an exercise very simple with straight code, for knowledge proposes. The executable works OK in Windows and Unbutu, but I can't realize how to do it in Mac.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should work exactly like Ubuntu. You need to give us more detail. What error(s) do you get? How do you run it on Ubuntu? How are you running it on the Mac? We should not be forced to guess.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. On Ubuntu I open the terminal put: